# Swift: How can I open a new window clicking a button?

Tags: macos, swift, window, xcode6

I'm new with this programming language and I'd like to create an application that opens a window with some information when I click a button but I don't know how to do that.

I'm not working with storyboards because I read that for professional programming these doesn't work.

I don't want for iOS, I'd like it to be for OS X.

Regards to all!

Comment: Of course lots of professional programs are using Storyboards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats pretty simple. You can do as follow:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    let myNewWindow = NSWindow(contentRect: NSMakeRect(0,0,640,480), styleMask: NSBorderlessWindowMask, backing: NSBackingStoreType.Buffered, defer: false)
    //        NSBorderlessWindowMask  = 0,
    //        NSTitledWindowMask  = 1 << 0,
    //        NSClosableWindowMask  = 1 << 1,
    //        NSMiniaturizableWindowMask  = 1 << 2,
    //        NSResizableWindowMask  = 1 << 3,
    //        NSTexturedBackgroundWindowMask  = 1 << 8
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application

    }
    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
    @IBAction func btnNewWindow(sender: AnyObject) {
        myNewWindow.opaque = false
        myNewWindow.movableByWindowBackground = true
        myNewWindow.backgroundColor = NSColor(hue: 0, saturation: 1, brightness: 0, alpha: 0.7)
        myNewWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: And how can I have control for that window? Like in the .xib file :/

Comment: I have added some other options for you. You can select the window you want to change its attributes and click at show Attributes Inspector (one of the top right side icons)

Comment: You can create your window using the xib as desired and then you just have to connect it to an outlet.

Comment: You just have to deselect visible at launch

Comment: This is what I have for now: 
import Cocoa
NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var windowCatalogos: NSWindow!
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }
    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
    IBAction func contenidoCatalogos(sender: AnyObject){
        windowCatalogos
    }
}  I don't know how to call my new window

Comment: I did it now and it worked only adding the "myNewWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)" method. Many thanks!

Comment: I cannot get this to work in a fresh project. I have copied all of this code and added it all into the applicationDidFinishLaunching function. I have been unable to set the outlet like @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow! but I cannot see how the window outlet is being referenced either. Thanks!

Comment: You are probably using storyboard. I will post a link to an answer that can help you