# Create window using view

Tags: xcode, swift, nswindow

How can I make a window in Swift that uses the same storyboard as my initial window? I've found [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27894070/4633828) that explain how to make a window, but that's just a blank window without any content. I've already got an initial window view controller - is there a way to make my new `NSWindow` use it?

Comment: You mean a copy of the window view? You can instantiate new copies of the view, but they will have the same viewController/same code.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. I'm new to programming Mac apps..

Comment: Me too, mostly an iOS person. I think you need something like `let newVC = MyViewController()` and `self.presentViewController()`, but I'm not sure of the syntax on the presentation part. Here's a nice tutorial for OS X: https://www.raywenderlich.com/111947/windows-and-window-controllers-in-os-x-tutorial