# Open window in macOS application in modal mode

Tags: swift, macos, nswindow, nsviewcontroller

I'm developing an application for macOS.

I've created all the interface within the main window. But now I need to open a new window to show information.

So I created a new .swift file of the NSViewController class with its .XIB.

What code should I use to open this new window in modal mode from the main window?

Comment: Hi, I did not find that topic. I read it now, but I do not understand how it configured the window ...

Comment: This solve my problem. But, how i open in modal mode?
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893796/swift-how-can-i-open-a-new-window-clicking-a-button

Comment: Yes, but... how i open the window in modal mode? Thx